# Java Timer in android

Tags: java, android, timer

How can this be done in android?

```
public final Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
          // Do task here       
        }
    });
```

I need to be able to call timer.start(); from the Activity that timer is in.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In most cases it is much better to use a Handler instead of Timer. Handler is capable of sending delayed messages. Benefits of using Handler are:

- it runs on the main (UI) thread -> can access Views (unlike the
  Timer, which cannot dircetly access Views)
- You can remove pending delayed messages if you want
- Less code

Example:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int DISPLAY_DATA = 1;
    // this handler will receive a delayed message
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // Do task here
            if (msg.what == DISPLAY_DATA) displayData();
        }
 };

 @Override
 void onCreate(Bundle b) {
     //this will post a message to the mHandler, which mHandler will get
     //after 5 seconds
     mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(DISPLAY_DATA, 5000);
 }
}
```

Comment: gives me Fatal exception Timer-0

Comment: ok got solved error, but how do i call this method lets say every 2 seconds?

Comment: If you want messages every two seconds, go for:

    ' private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // Do task here
            if (msg.what == DISPLAY_DATA) displayData();
            mHandler.postEmptyMessageDelayed(DISPLAY_DATA, 2000);
        }
     };'

Rr you can send messages to the Handler from a timer.

Comment: and how do I stop this timer?

Comment: This is not a Timer, this is a delayed message. To remove it call mHandler.removeMessages(DISPLAY_DATA);

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
// this will run when timer elapses
TimerTask myTimerTask = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // ...
    }

};

// new timer
Timer timer = new Timer();

// schedule timer
timer.schedule(myTimerTask, delayInMs);
```

If you want task to be done in activity's main thread, modify it like this:

```
// get a handler (call from main thread)
final Handler handler = new Handler();

// this will run when timer elapses
TimerTask myTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // post a runnable to the handler
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // ...
            }
        });
    }
};

// new timer
Timer timer = new Timer();

// schedule timer
timer.schedule(myTimerTask, delayInMs);
```

Comment: Instead using a `Handler` you could simply call `runOnUiThread(Runnable)`.

Answer (score 4):

Android has a nice [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) class, too

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this in another question.

I would avoid the TimerTask, if you fire a lot of them off, they are not only difficult to manage but bad for performance.

I would recommend a `Handler` for pretty much any Time based task these days.

See [Timer application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100196/making-a-interval-timer-in-java-android)